# How can I paste my m-file into simulink?

Tags: signals, simulink, matlab

I created a program and want to use it in `simulink`. How can I paste my `m-file` into `simulink`?

The program extrapolates input signal.

```
Input: N-vector (need to collect N values ​​of input signal)
Output: number (value of input function in future)
```

and then repeat;

And how can I get `N-vector` from `signal` and discretization time?

Answer (score 0):

There is a block in simulink after 2010b that is called " embedded matlab code ", where you can define a typical function of matlab that runs every calculation step of simulink. Is that what you needed? 
I think you can also give a "enable" signal to you block (if not, make one manually as an input) to run your code only when you want. hope it helps